# Some basic logging with NLog

Tags: c#, nlog

I am facing some very simple basic problem with NLog working. I have config file as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <targets>
    <target xsi:type="File"
      name="file"
      layout="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message}"
      archiveAboveSize="4000"
      maxArchiveFiles="1"
      archiveFileName="${basedir}/log_archived.txt"
      fileName="log.txt" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="file" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

In my c# proj I am doing this

```
class Program
    {
        private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                logger.Fatal("Sample fatal error message::  {0}", i);
            }
```

The log.txt file is

2013-11-26 11:10:06.7166|FATAL|ConsoleApplication1.Program|Sample fatal error message::  0
2013-11-26 11:10:06.7366|FATAL|ConsoleApplication1.Program|Sample fatal error message::  1
2013-11-26 11:10:06.7366|FATAL|ConsoleApplication1.Program|Sample fatal error message::  2
2013-11-26 11:10:06.7366|FATAL|ConsoleApplication1.Program|Sample fatal error message::  3
2013-11-26 11:10:06.7366|FATAL|ConsoleApplication1.Program|Sample fatal error message::  4
2013-11-26 11:10:06.7366|FATAL|ConsoleApplication1.Program|Sample fatal error message::  5
2013-11-26 11:10:06.7466|FATAL|ConsoleApplication1.Program|Sample fatal error message::  6
2013-11-26 11:10:06.7466|FATAL|ConsoleApplication1.Program|Sample fatal error message::  7
2013-11-26 11:10:06.7466|FATAL|ConsoleApplication1.Program|Sample fatal error message::  8
2013-11-26 11:10:06.7466|FATAL|ConsoleApplication1.Program|Sample fatal error message::  9
2013-11-26 11:10:06.7466|FATAL|ConsoleApplication1.Program|Sample fatal error message::  10
2013-11-26 11:10:06.7466|FATAL|ConsoleApplication1.Program|Sample fatal error message::  11
2013-11-26 11:10:06.7466|FATAL|ConsoleApplication1.Program|Sample fatal error message::  12
2013-11-26 11:10:06.7466|FATAL|ConsoleApplication1.Program|Sample fatal error message::  13
2013-11-26 11:10:06.7466|FATAL|ConsoleApplication1.Program|Sample fatal error message::  14
2013-11-26 11:10:06.7466|FATAL|ConsoleApplication1.Program|Sample fatal error message::  15
2013-11-26 11:10:06.7466|FATAL|ConsoleApplication1.Program|Sample fatal error message::  16
2013-11-26 11:10:06.7466|FATAL|ConsoleApplication1.Program|Sample fatal error message::  17
2013-11-26 11:10:06.7466|FATAL|ConsoleApplication1.Program|Sample fatal error message::  18
2013-11-26 11:10:06.7466|FATAL|ConsoleApplication1.Program|Sample fatal error message::  19
2013-11-26 11:10:06.7466|FATAL|ConsoleApplication1.Program|Sample fatal error message::  20
2013-11-26 11:10:06.7466|FATAL|ConsoleApplication1.Program|Sample fatal error message::  21
2013-11-26 11:10:06.7466|FATAL|ConsoleApplication1.Program|Sample fatal error message::  22
2013-11-26 11:10:06.7466|FATAL|ConsoleApplication1.Program|Sample fatal error message::  23
2013-11-26 11:10:06.7466|FATAL|ConsoleApplication1.Program|Sample fatal error message::  24
2013-11-26 11:10:06.7466|FATAL|ConsoleApplication1.Program|Sample fatal error message::  25
2013-11-26 11:10:06.7466|FATAL|ConsoleApplication1.Program|Sample fatal error message::  26
2013-11-26 11:10:06.7466|FATAL|ConsoleApplication1.Program|Sample fatal error message::  27
2013-11-26 11:10:06.7466|FATAL|ConsoleApplication1.Program|Sample fatal error message::  28
2013-11-26 11:10:06.7466|FATAL|ConsoleApplication1.Program|Sample fatal error message::  29
2013-11-26 11:10:06.7466|FATAL|ConsoleApplication1.Program|Sample fatal error message::  30
2013-11-26 11:10:06.7466|FATAL|ConsoleApplication1.Program|Sample fatal error message::  31
2013-11-26 11:10:06.7466|FATAL|ConsoleApplication1.Program|Sample fatal error message::  32
2013-11-26 11:10:06.7466|FATAL|ConsoleApplication1.Program|Sample fatal error message::  33
2013-11-26 11:10:06.7666|FATAL|ConsoleApplication1.Program|Sample fatal error message::  34
2013-11-26 11:10:06.7666|FATAL|ConsoleApplication1.Program|Sample fatal error message::  35
2013-11-26 11:10:06.7666|FATAL|ConsoleApplication1.Program|Sample fatal error message::  36
2013-11-26 11:10:06.7666|FATAL|ConsoleApplication1.Program|Sample fatal error message::  37
2013-11-26 11:10:06.7666|FATAL|ConsoleApplication1.Program|Sample fatal error message::  38
2013-11-26 11:10:06.7666|FATAL|ConsoleApplication1.Program|Sample fatal error message::  39
2013-11-26 11:10:06.7666|FATAL|ConsoleApplication1.Program|Sample fatal error message::  40

(size exceed 4K)

Now according to expected result I should have a archive file with the old data and log.txt file with the latest entries from 100, 99,98.... But what is happening that when the size of log.txt file exceeds the mentioned limit. Logging stops and no new archive file is created.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine to me. After program run I have two files in application directory:

- `log.txt` with entries 86-99 of size 1302 bytes
- `log_archived.txt` with entries 43-85 of size 3999 bytes

Make sure you are looking at correct directory. Also make sure you have correct `NLog.config` in application directory

Comment: thanks again for your time. its driving me crazy i dont know whats the mistake at my end

Comment: @user2968369 open your application folder, check `NLog.config` is there and verify it has correct settings. Then run `exe` file (not from Visual Studio!) and verify whether log files will appear

Comment: Yes i followed these steps. again only one file log.txt is there :(

Comment: @user2968369 I suggest you to delete log files and re-run your application

Comment: I deleted. Then again i add new log file by clicking on project->Add->New ITem->NLog->Empty Nlog Configuration File.

Then change Copy to Output Directory-> Copy always

So now two log files one where project.cs is and one with the .exe file. 

Still same one file is forming

Comment: any thing you can add here

Comment: @user2968369 you should delete log file, not configuration file (just make sure configuration is valid) and re-run your exe